# What is the host address in the socket_bind function?

Tags: php, sockets

I am using wamp server. In the local host I can use the IP 127.0.0.1 as given below when binding socket to port. But in the case of real web hosting what value should be assigned to the $host variable? Should it be the IP address of the webserver or else?

```
 <?php
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $port = 25003;
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

    // bind socket to port
    $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
    //some code....
    ?>
```

Comment: It should be the IP *of the interface on the local network*, whatever that is. This may be the same as the external IP or it may be different if routing/NAT is used.

Comment: in a real webhosting usually what address value is assigned to the host variable as mentioned in the question? @user2864740

Comment: Ask the webhost used. They should provide all that information.

Comment: tnq,, but is it webhost related issue? @user2864740

Comment: No. Your software should be agnostic to the deployment environment. You'll either bind to the interface by name or by address (in the case of an AF_INET family socket). If NATing is used, your script won't care as that will be handled externally.